# How to include MapBox v5 with Android Gradle?

Tags: mapbox

I added the dependency for MapBox `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.0-beta.3` as `compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.0-beta.3'` stated from [here](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk%3Amapbox-android-sdk/5.0.0-beta.3#) or [here](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.mapbox.mapboxsdk%7Cmapbox-android-sdk%7C5.0.0-beta.3%7Cjar). But when i run this, I receive this error:

> Error:Module 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.0-beta.3'
>   depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar.

I thought of changing it to get the @aar instead just like this:

```
compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.0-beta.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
```

I ran it and it builds fine. But when I build my app, it throws a bunch of compile errors like it cannot resolve `app:style_url` or any other `MapView` specific xml attributes.

I also tried adding MapBox directly from Android Studio to no avail.

How can I use MapBox `5.0.0-beta.3` in Android? Am I missing something? I am still using v4.2.2 and I have some [issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/6761) and it seems that they have merge it with `v5.0.0-beta.3` and requested to try it and so I did.

What am I missing? Can I just download the actual .aar files so I can just include it manually?

Here is gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "#############"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.2.33"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable "ResourceType"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'ca.barrenechea.header-decor:header-decor:0.2.8'
    compile('com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.2.2@aar'
}
```

Thanks!